# 1 data, many applications

Tags: database, kohana, vbulletin

I have a forum with >400 registered users. It's powered by vBulletin-4.0.4. I want to build up several websites with kohana-3.1, but keep existing forum users too. I will use seperate databases for each application (I want to keep apps as independent as possible).
So my solution is:
step 1. create special app `users.mydomain.com` where each user can register and update their details *(birthdate/email/password)*. This app will catch all changes and write them to forum database and application databases.
step 2. modify default auth module to handle forum authentication. vBulletin uses algorithm: `$hash=MD5(MD5($password)+$salt)` for pass hashing.

Am I in the right direction? Is it OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has already done this: [Kohana vBulletin Bridge](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/3394/vbulletin-bridge-ko2/p1). You will need to contact the author of the module as the source code is no longer online. It wont be too difficult to upgrade it to 3 if you get it.

I haven't used vBulletin so I can't give you much advice on the subject, but you're right about the hashing algorithm. You'll also need to make sure your session is read and written as they are in vBulletin.

A quick search of [vBulletin SSO](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=vbulletin+sso) to get you started.